# React Component crashes on reload

Tags: reactjs

I have a `notes-list` component that gets the notes data as props from the main component.
Inside the `notes-list`component, there is a `notes-item` component which has a dynamic route that loads `notesItem-page`. So, for every `notes-item` there is a dynamic url for it's respective `notesItem-page`which has all the details about the `notesItem` object. I use `Link` from `react-router-dom`
The `notes-list` component looks like this:

```
export class NotesList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { isLoggedIn } = this.props.loggedInContext;

    return (
      <div className="notes-list">
        {this.props.notes.map((notesItem) => (
          <Link
            to={{
              pathname: `${notesItem.slug}`,
              id: notesItem._id,
            }}
            style={{
              textDecoration: "none",
              color: "#fea82f",
            }}
          >
            <NotesItem notes={notesItem} />
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default loggedInContext(NotesList);
```

This successfully redirects me to the NotesItem-page with the correct props and inside the notesItem-page I get the receive the id of the object that I had passed as props and make an API call with that particular id in ComponentDidMount() method.
This works perfectly. However, it crashes on reload. It gives the following error:

[image]

I am guessing it is because of ComponentDidMount works only once,but I do not seem to find an alternate solution to this problem.

The notesItem-page component looks like this:

```
export class notesItemPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      notesItem: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/notes/fetch/${this.props.location.id}`)
      .then((notesItem) => notesItem.json())
      .then((notesItem) =>
        this.setState({ notesItem: notesItem.data, isLoaded: true })
      );
  }
  render() {
    const { notesItem } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="notesItem-details">
        <h1> {notesItem.title} Notes</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default notesItemPage;
```

It would be great if anyone could help me with this, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean crashes?

Comment: ^ I am sorry I forgot to mention that. I have edited the post with the error.

Comment: The fetch call might take a few seconds to actually complete and update the state. Until then, `state.notesItem` will be undefined, but render is surely likely to get called anyway.

Comment: Also, don't paste pictures of errors. Paste the actual error text. Simply cop and paste and format as code.

Comment: Okay, will keep that in mind. Thank you very much.

Comment: @selbie Even if it completes fetching the data from the API, the render would have been executed by then right?

Comment: @Shockhandler - Correct.  `render` might get called multiple times during the lifetime of your page - before and after the fetch has completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is here:

```
<h1> {notesItem.title} Notes</h1>
```

here the `notesItem` is coming from an axios call and this data is not available on the time of first component render and this is causing the issue ( app crash ).

So change this:

```
<h1> {notesItem.title} Notes</h1>
```

to

```
<h1> { notesItem && notesItem.title } Notes</h1>  // use it when it is available from axios call
```